# React project run command throws errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack, node-modules

I tried running my React.js project. It uses `typeScript` and `webpack`, however I encountered a bunch of errors when running the command `npm run dev` (please see the attached snippet).

What I tried is:

1. Delete the `node_modules` directory.
2. Delete the `package-lock.json` file.
3. Run `npm i`
   Result: **No change**

Then I tried:

1. Delete the `node_modules` directory.
2. Delete the `package-lock.json` file.
3. Run `npm install -g typescript@latest`
4. Run `npm i`
   Result: **No change**

Then I tried:

1. Delete the `node_modules` directory.
2. Delete the `package-lock.json` file.
3. Replacing the following files with the version from a colleague, `package.json`, `webpack.dev.js` and `webpack.prod.js`.
4. Run `npm i`
   Result: **No change** (However, for that guy it freaking works)

- Snippet of errors thrown:
  [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0anG.png)

I tried running the project and expect it to run without issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using typescript you must have a tsconfig.json file. The issue may be caused by a bad path specified in that file when you start your app.

You can checkout de documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

Comment: This is the configuration specification:    `{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./dist",
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "es6",
  "jsx": "react",
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "allowJs": true,
 }
}`